# can't access deployed docker service via browser

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm working on docker swarm mode, after initializing the swarm with a specific address, `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-stack.yml vote`
the is the output of `docker stack services vote` :

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                          PORTS
5dh33wz0v7a3        vote_worker         replicated          1/1                 dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest   
9zm4elw08msm        vote_visualizer     replicated          1/1                 dockersamples/visualizer:stable                *:8080->8080/tcp
d1718zjchc47        vote_vote           replicated          2/2                 dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before     *:5000->80/tcp
hid5yic9xcmf        vote_redis          replicated          1/1                 redis:alpine                                   
mr474cnourx6        vote_result         replicated          1/1                 dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before   *:5001->80/tcp
pk3hoto6j39m        vote_db             replicated          1/1                 postgres:9.4
```

with curl http://localhost:8080 or any exposed port i get the output but when i do it via browser it hangs and nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need check wich ip has container , [you can found in docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/), probably you need change docker configuration.

```
docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"
```

Comment: change docker configuration to what ?

Comment: to change current network configuration https://docs.docker.com/network/ , to use localhost

Comment: I figured it out by accessing it via the IP given in --advertise-addr option

Comment: can you share your docker swarm command ? I have the same issue, i've tried using command "docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.121" but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Application needs to be accessed with the IP given in `--advertise-addr` option